# How to create a manifest appsscript.json file for Google Apps Scrips for creating Gmail Labels

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I created an app in Apps Script and conected it to Google Cloud Project under Workspace Marketplace SDK API.
The script is very simple and just create gmail labels when you run it. I added a trigger in the Apps Script that should run daily so if I update the app with new labels I want it to push them to all the users in the organization with the app installed. This is just an internal app.
I'm having problems getting approved after submiting it. I think the last part I need is the manifest file and I'm not sure what I need in there to get approved. This is what I corrently have, any suggestions (I added the scopes, everything else was there):

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Denver",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I got rejected from Google

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes), what you did is you included the scopes that was defined in the article above.

You can try using these scopes instead:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
  ],
```

### Update

As requested here is the sample manifest that I used to create the add-on:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "<insert Add-on name>",
    "logoUrl": "<insert logo URL>",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't have to add anything else to the manifest? I see in the documentation all kinds of information and I wasn't sure what to add to the manifest.

Comment: I tried to create a test add-on on my end and use those oauthScopes and it works fine. I only added some information below for the add-on name, logoURL and contextualTriggers since the add-on that I create assign the label on the email that is open.

contextualTriggers is used as a list of triggers that fire when a message is opened in Gmail. When the trigger fires, it executes a specific Apps Script function, usually to create new cards and update the UI. As per this [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/gmail-addons).

Comment: would you share your manifest so I could see how to add the add-on name and logo? Thank you

Comment: Here is the sample manifest:

{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "<insert add-on name>",
    "logoUrl": "<insert logo>",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
 "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
}
}

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I have also added an update to my answer with the manifest that I used to create the add-on.